# How to make a new table row after 30 iterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I tried to make a for loop make new table rows, because my colspan overflow inside my table. I was thinking to make new footer after 30 rows, but I had problems with the tr.

```
newFooter = '<tfoot style="border: solid 1px"><td colspan="11">'

for (var index = 1; index < 30; index++) {
    newFooter = newFooter + '<tr><td><label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="' + index + '">' + index + '</td></tr></label>'
```

oh okay...

fix about 70% after i done..

```
newFooter = '<tfoot style="border: solid 1px"><td colspan="11"></td>'

                                        for (var index = 1; index <= totalIndex; index++) {
                                            if (index % 30 == 1 && index != 1) {
                                                newFooter += "</tr><tr>";
                                            }
                                            newFooter = newFooter + '<label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="' + index + '">' + index + '</label>'
                                        }

                                        newFooter = newFooter + '</tfoot>';


}

newFooter = newFooter + '</td></tfoot>';
$("#tblCausebook").last().append(newFooter);
```

But i have problem with td, it keep looping together

Almost there, but now i keep on looping tr...

```
   newFooter = '<tfoot style="border: solid 1px">'


                                        for (var index = 1; index <= totalIndex; index++) {

                                            newFooter += '<tr><td colspan="11">'

                                            if (index % 3 == 1 && index != 1) {
                                                newFooter += "</tr><tr>";
                                            }
                                            newFooter = newFooter + '<label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="' + index + '">' + index + '</label>'
                                        }

                                        newFooter = newFooter + '</td></tr></tfoot>';
                                        $("#tblCausebook").last().append(newFooter);
```

OK,,, FINALIZING MY RESULT :) IM DONE, THANKS FOR YOU HELPS GUYS! ESP, CORY

```
   newFooter = '<tfoot style="border: solid 1px">'


                                        for (var index = 1; index <= totalIndex; index++) {

                                            if (index % 10 == 1 && index != 0) {
                                                newFooter += "</tr><tr><td colspan='11'>";
                                            }
                                            newFooter = newFooter + '<label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="' + index + '">' + index + '</label>'
                                        }

                                        newFooter = newFooter + '</td></tr></tfoot>';
                                        $("#tblCausebook").last().append(newFooter);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "had a problem"? What didn't work? Did you get an error?

Comment: Why is the `</label>` outside of the `</tr>` when the `<label ...>` tag was opened inside the `<td>`?

Comment: There's a variety of mismatched tags here. 1. You're trying to put `tr`s inside a `td`. That's not going to work at all. 2. Your `</label>` should come before the `</td>` on that line.  What do you *actually* want the final HTML to look like?

Comment: yes i see , because i trying to make alot tr, that why it didt come out

Comment: @Cory no just it didt come out

Comment: @PaulRoub i want it to be like this

<tr><td> <label>123</label><label>123</label><label>123</label></<td></tr>

Comment: Are you try to add 30 Table Rows, and each row has one `td` that spans 11 columns?

Comment: @Cory should i remove it?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/5mnxgetp/

Comment: @Cory yes, but i dont want loop together with td, is that possible?

Comment: i going lunch be back at 30min

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for - I added a space between lables, but you can take it out if you want:

```
 var newFooter = '<tfoot style="border: solid 1px"><tr><td colspan="11">'

 for (var index = 1; index < 30; index++) {
 newFooter = newFooter + '<label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="' + index + '">' + index + ' ' + '</label>'
 }

 newFooter = newFooter + '</td></tr></tfoot>';
 $("#tblCausebook").last().append(newFooter);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mnxgetp/1/)

Comment: hii cory , almost correct, but i want every 30 label with new tr.. sample with 2 label with new tr...

<tr><td colspan="11"><label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="1">1 </label><label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="2">2 </label></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="11"><label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="1">3 </label><label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="2">4 </label></td></tr>

Comment: That will give you 30 rows. That is not a footer. Do you have a picture of what you want it to look like?

Comment: this is the best preview , if i edited from html.

<tfoot style="border: solid 1px"><tr><td colspan="11"><label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="31">31</label></td></tr><tr><td colspan="11"><label data-type="btnIndex" data-index="61">61</label>
  </td></tr></tfoot>

Comment: thanks for you help! i done it :P thanks so much...!